# Bootstrap Tooltip/Popover not working (Using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Bootstrap Tooltip not working]

I want to use Bootstrap tooltip to give some extra information from that `td#row0_colcode`, it works in HTML, but with jQuery `.append()` doesn't.

I have already put the `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` inside of `$(document).ready(...)` and it didn't work neither.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, I only needed to add

```
$('body').tooltip({selector:'[data-toggle=tooltip]'});
```

to my code!